# How to read data from a file into a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am trying to read information from a.txt file where each label is a dictionary key and each associated column of readings is the respective value.

Here's some lines in the file:

```
increments ideal actual measured
0.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1006.4882
1.0, 950.0, 973.2774, 994.5579
2.0, 902.5, 897.6053, 998.9594
3.0, 857.375, 863.4304, 847.4721
4.0, 814.5062, 813.8886, 866.4862
```

```py
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    labels = file.readline().rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    num_cols = len(labels)
    data = [[] for _ in range(num_cols)] 
    data_dict = {}
```

The above code is correct I just need to add on a little bit.
How do I get the labels as dictionary keys and the columns as its values into data_dict?

Comment: `with open(filename) as infile): answer = {float(line.split(',',1)[0]):list(map(float(line.strip().split(', ')[1:]))) for line in infile}`

Comment: Try [`csv`](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) module

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. I missunderstood what you were trying yo do

Comment: Not clear how you want to handle the multiple rows of values. Do you expect one dict with labels as keys and list of values (representing the columns) as values? Or do you want a dict for each row and end up with a list of dicts?

Comment: I want a dictionary where each word is a dictionary key and the key is associated with its column of values. I want to be able to do data.pop('increments') and it to give me the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```py
with open("test.csv", 'r') as file:
    
    labels = file.readline().rstrip('\n').split() # read first line for labels
    data_dict = {l:[] for l in labels} # init empty container for each label

    for line in file.readlines(): # loop through rest of lines
        data = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        for n, datapoint in enumerate(data):
            data_dict[labels[n]].append(datapoint)

print(data_dict)
# >>> {'increments': ['0.0', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0'], 'ideal': [' 1000.0', ' 950.0', ' 902.5', ' 857.375', ' 814.5062'], 'actual': [' 1000.0', ' 973.2774', ' 897.6053', ' 863.4304', ' 813.8886'], 'measured': [' 1006.4882', ' 994.5579', ' 998.9594', ' 847.4721', ' 866.4862']}
```

I was a bit confused about your input file. Your data seems to be comma separated but your headers are space separated? The concept here is basically that you create the dict with empty lists and then you can use the `enumerate` function and append the datapoint to the appropriate header. Hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome! You can vote up the answer if it helped you

Comment: I would I don't have enough reputation yet. I appreciate the help a lot though

Comment: You should now!

Comment: Thank you! You earned your upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to solve this

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict  = pd.read_csv('a.txt', sep=' ').to_dict(orient="index").values()
```

Comment: That gave the wrong results and importing outside stuff isn't allowed.